# One or Nothing Validation Rule

Tags: validation-rule

Need to create a validation rule that will evaluate 5 picklist fields and this are the requirements:

1. Only one field can have a value regardless which one of the 5 fields
2. all fields can be blank

This is what I created:

```
OR(
ISBLANK(TEXT(Three_Sixty_Retail_Rate__c)),
NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT( Channel_Sale_Rate__c ))),
NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT( Claremont_Sale_Rate__c ))),
NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT( Developer_Sale_Rate__c ))),
NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT( Three_Sixty_Referral_Rate__c ))))
```

But this does not work if all is blank.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps

```
IF(ISBLANK(TEXT(Three_Sixty_Retail_Rate__c)),0,1)+
IF(ISBLANK(TEXT(Three_Sixty_Retail_Rate__c)),0,1)+
IF(ISBLANK(TEXT(Claremont_Sale_Rate__c )),0,1)+
IF(ISBLANK(TEXT(Developer_Sale_Rate__c  )),0,1)+
IF(ISBLANK(TEXT(Three_Sixty_Referral_Rate__c )),0,1)>1
```

Answer (score -1):

This can Work

```
IF(IF(ISBLANK(TEXT(Three_Sixty_Retail_Rate__c)),0,1)+IF(ISBLANK(TEXT(Three_Sixty_Retail_Rate__c)),0,1)+IF(ISBLANK(TEXT(Claremont_Sale_Rate__c )),0,1)+IF(ISBLANK(TEXT(Developer_Sale_Rate__c  )),0,1)+IF(ISBLANK(TEXT(Three_Sixty_Referral_Rate__c   )),0,1)==1||IF(ISBLANK(TEXT(Three_Sixty_Retail_Rate__c)),0,1)+IF(ISBLANK(TEXT(Three_Sixty_Retail_Rate__c)),0,1)+IF(ISBLANK(TEXT(Claremont_Sale_Rate__c )),0,1)+IF(ISBLANK(TEXT(Developer_Sale_Rate__c  )),0,1)+IF(ISBLANK(TEXT(Three_Sixty_Referral_Rate__c   )),0,1)==0,False,True)
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try!